# Http streaming ( Simulating live data streams using CSV)

Tags: java, http, streaming, http-live-streaming

I am new to Java. Can someone please help with some code snippet or tips, using which I am live stream data from web server to client app. A java Op in my web server is reading a CSV, one row (each row has 15 integer values) every 20 milliseconds and I want client app to get this data every 20 ms.

Is live streaming the right way ? There are two ways (As per whatever I googled) - Push / Pull. I did not really understood them well and difference between them and which can one is more suited for the purpose. 
And how this push/pull thing is different form live streaming of data.

Can Http Live streaming at all be used for data or just for audio/video. 
Experts, please help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Http Live Streaming specifies that the stream with be MPEG2 transport stream, mp3, or AAC stream.

You are "barking up the wrong tree". You will probably want to go for a simple loop with a timer in java, and ignore any HLS libraries.